# Submitting for python

Tags: python, html, flask, process, form-submit

So I am trying to make a form that accepts text when submitted and returns submitted text using the `/process` function.

Here is my code for `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Whats my name</title>
      <h1>What's my name?</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text">
        <form action="POST"
        >
           <p>your name</p><input type="submit">

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my Python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,redirect  # Import Flask to allow us to create our app, and import
                                          # render_template to allow us to render index.html.
app = Flask(__name__)                     # Global variable __name__ tells Flask whether or not we
                                          # are running the file directly or importing it as a module.
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/process',methods=['POST'])
def input():
    return redirect  ('/')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the name value from your html you'll have to add a tag `name` to the input.
Please see example below, here I named it `user_name`:

```
<html>
    {...}
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
           <input type="text" name="user_name"/>
           <p>your name</p>
           <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then request the value in your backend Python code

```
# import the needed request module from Flask
from flask import request

(...)

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def input():
    name = request.form['user_name']
    return name
```

Comment: I don't think the `if request.method == 'POST':` is necessary, since methods list in the route only has POST. Also the action in the form is wrong, and method misses double quotes.

Comment: `if request.method == 'POST':` is needed to check if the form has been submitted by the user. If it returns `True` then we can return the value from the input

Comment: Basically you want to make sure that the request is a "POST". The truth is that the route function only accepts "POST" requests, since you already have `methods=['POST']`. If you add "GET" or "DELETE" in the methods list, then the if statement is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out first: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Action should be "/process" instead of "POST".
Method is "POST". Also you will need input elements in the form to allow user inputs something.

The input value can be retrieved on the flask side by `request.form['value of name attribute of input']`

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

I would like to recommend you to use https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ flask wtf to generate form and retrieve users' input.